# XCart unable to add items to cart

Tags: x-cart

Hey guys I'm taking over another web developers installation of XCart and am unable to
add items to a cart, it seems like they disabled this functionality somehow, and am wondering
if there are thoughts on how this has been done. You can play with an actual item here

[Item Test](http://www.universalchurchsupplies.org/Alpha-Omega-Stole-with-Tassels.html)

To see what it actually does. It seems like the item completely skips the cart somehow, I'm
wondering if this is a product irregularity? All products were imported, none were created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fear I can't test that. You don't have any "add-to-cart" buttons enabled on that web-site pages.

If this is what you faced to - make sure
1) you have "add-to-cart" code in product.tpl template file
2) you have non-zero in-stock qty for products
3) at least one of payment methods enabled